# Rock,paper,scissors Tally counter python

Tags: python

I am using Python. Currently new to it. I'm creating a rock paper scissors game with win counter. I've look up some solution online but it doesn't work for me.I'm close to completing it.But there's just an error to it.I can't get the tally counter working.It doesn't shows any win count at the end of the program

```
from random import randint

print ("Rock ,Paper,Scissors game.")

#Function to get computer input
def generate():
    comlist = ["rock","paper","scissors"]
    comans = comlist[randint(-1,2)]
    if comans == "rock":
        print ("Computer choose rock.")
    elif comans == "paper" :
        print ("Computer choose paper.")
    elif comans == "scissors":
        print ("Computer choose scissors.")
    return comans

#Function to get user input
def user():
    userchoice = input ("Choose rock, paper , or scissors.")
    while userchoice != 'rock' and userchoice != 'paper' and userchoice != 'scissors':
        print ("Invalid input. Please enter again")
        userchoice = input ("Choose rock, paper , or scissors.")
    if userchoice == "rock":
        print ("You  choose rock.")
        choice = userchoice
    elif userchoice == "paper" :
        print ("You choose paper.")
        choice = userchoice
    else:
        userchoice == "scissors"
        print ("You choose scissors.")
        choice = userchoice
    return choice

#Function to determine winner
def result(comans ,choice):
    global result_set
    if choice == comans:
        print ("Tie")
    elif choice == "rock":
        if computer == "paper":
            print ("You lose")
        else :
            print("You win")
            result_set ='win'
    elif choice == "paper":
        if computer == "scissors":
            print("You lose")
        else:
            print("You win")
            result_set ='win'
    elif choice == "scissors":
        if computer == "rock":
            print("You lose")
        else:
            print("You win")
            result_set ='win'

#Function to get win taly
def wincounter (result,guess,computer):
    if result_set == 'win':
        win += 1
    else:
        pass
    print (win)

#Main program
counter = 0
win = 0
diffulty = input(' Please enter diffulty.( "1" for easy , "2" for medium, "3" for hard)')
while diffulty != '1' and diffulty != '2' and diffulty != '3':
    print ('Invalid input')
    diffulty = input(' Please enter diffulty.( "1" for easy , "2" for medium, "3" for hard)')
if diffulty == '1':
    print ("You have choose easy")
    counter = 1
    guess = user()
    computer = generate()
    result (computer, guess)
    while counter < 3:
        guess = user()
        computer = generate()
        result (computer, guess)
        counter +=1
if diffulty == '2':
    print ("You have choose medium")
    counter = 1
    guess = user()
    computer = generate()
    result (computer, guess)
    while counter < 5:
        guess = user()
        computer = generate()
        result (computer, guess)
        counter +=1
if diffulty == '3':
    print ("You have choose hard")
    counter = 1
    guess = user()
    computer = generate()
    result (computer, guess)
    while counter < 10:
        guess = user()
        computer = generate()
        result (computer, guess)
        counter +=1
```

Here is my code. It is slightly messy. Sorry for that since than I am still new in python. Thanks for the help.
After running.

```
  Choose rock, paper , or scissors.rock
You  choose rock.
Computer choose scissors.
You win
Choose rock, paper , or scissors.rock
You  choose rock.
Computer choose rock.
Tie
Choose rock, paper , or scissors.rock
You  choose rock.
Computer choose rock.
Tie
```

It is suppose to show the win results after the end of the last round.

Comment: what is the problem now? What is not working?

Comment: First please explain what "not working" is: crash? wrong results?... Then please only show (or at least highlight the relevant part), no one really likes reading through 100s of lines of code. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: You don't use the parameters to your wincounter function

Comment: sorry..edited. it's just doesn't show any win count at the end of the program

Comment: @JimYong How do you want your win count to be displayed? tell me example of win count you want to see.

Comment: @JimYong I have fixed your code check it out and let me know if there is any difficulties understanding it or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed your code . . .

```
from random import randint

print ("Rock ,Paper,Scissors game.")

#Function to get computer input
def generate():
    comlist = ["rock","paper","scissors"]
    comans = comlist[randint(-1,2)]
    if comans == "rock":
        print ("Computer choose rock.")
    elif comans == "paper" :
        print ("Computer choose paper.")
    elif comans == "scissors":
        print ("Computer choose scissors.")
    return comans

#Function to get user input
def user():
    userchoice = input ("Choose rock, paper , or scissors.")
    while userchoice != 'rock' and userchoice != 'paper' and userchoice != 'scissors':
        print ("Invalid input. Please enter again")
        userchoice = input ("Choose rock, paper , or scissors.")
    if userchoice == "rock":
        print ("You  choose rock.")
        choice = userchoice
    elif userchoice == "paper" :
        print ("You choose paper.")
        choice = userchoice
    else:
        userchoice == "scissors"
        print ("You choose scissors.")
        choice = userchoice
    return choice

#Function to determine winner
def result(comans ,choice):
    result_set = ''
    if choice == comans:
        print ("Tie")
    elif choice == "rock":
        if computer == "paper":
            print ("You lose")
        else :
            print("You win")
            result_set ='win'
    elif choice == "paper":
        if computer == "scissors":
            print("You lose")
        else:
            print("You win")
            result_set ='win'
    elif choice == "scissors":
        if computer == "rock":
            print("You lose")
        else:
            print("You win")
            result_set ='win'

    wincounter(result_set)

#Function to get win taly
def wincounter (result):
    global win
    if result == 'win':
        win += 1
    else:
        pass
   #print (win)


def print_win_count():
    global win
    print ('you have win '+ str(win) + ' times')

#Main program
counter = 0
win = 0
diffulty = input(' Please enter diffulty.( "1" for easy , "2" for medium, "3" for hard)')
while diffulty != '1' and diffulty != '2' and diffulty != '3':
    print ('Invalid input')
    diffulty = input(' Please enter diffulty.( "1" for easy , "2" for medium, "3" for hard)')
if diffulty == '1':
    print ("You have choose easy")
    counter = 1
    guess = user()
    computer = generate()
    result (computer, guess)
    while counter < 3:
        guess = user()
        computer = generate()
        result (computer, guess)
        counter +=1
    print_win_count()
if diffulty == '2':
    print ("You have choose medium")
    counter = 1
    guess = user()
    computer = generate()
    result (computer, guess)
    while counter < 5:
        guess = user()
        computer = generate()
        result (computer, guess)
        counter +=1
    print_win_count()
if diffulty == '3':
    print ("You have choose hard")
    counter = 1
    guess = user()
    computer = generate()
    result (computer, guess)
    while counter < 10:
        guess = user()
        computer = generate()
        result (computer, guess)
        counter +=1
    print_win_count(0)
```

Comment: oh wow..thanks alot